# mailgun email configuration with parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, mailgun

I am using parse.com and Mailgun to send emails. But when I tried to send email I see the error that says

> "The domain is unverified and requires DNS configuration. Log in to
>   your control panel to view required DNS
>   records\\"\n}\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"The domain is unverified and
>   requires DNS configuration. Log in to your control panel to view
>   required DNS records\"

I could see that my DNS is not verified in Mailgun dashboard as well.

If I use a custom domain I can do these configurations with the domain provider panel.

But I am using default xxx.parseapp.com as my domain for now.

How to do the setting for this scenario. I couldn't find any place to do the TXT settings in parse.com

Comment: same problem to me. I'm trying to find out a solution right now

Comment: @tylyo no idea how to solve it, I din't want to invest anything now to buy a hosting space and move it instead of using parse.com, but looks like that is the only option. Parse support through stackoverflow sucks..